# Use Prepopulated Database or Not? For my Android studio app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to make an app that has a list of quotes (maybe 1000++) and each user can choose the quotes that they like by clicking the favorite button (When its clicked,  it updates the database so the database knew which quotes that the user favorited.).

And theres a Favorites Activity which display all of the user's favorite quotes

So my questions is

1) Should i use Prepopulated Database (using sqlite browser and put it on the assets folder) or Create the database and insert the list of quotes in OnCreate Method

2) If i use Prepopulated Database can i update the value? (I want to update the favorite table everytime the user click the favorite quotes) because i heard if i put it on asset folder,  its a read only?

3) Which one should i use to make this app? I have tried all of them but still confused. Because on each tutorials website has different way of doing this

Sorry if i asked some noob questions

**Edited Post**

So what you mean is, when i copy my .db files that i got from sqlite browser. And put it in the assets/databases folder, it became writable ?? so i should use pre-populated database??

here's my current code if you like to see

**DatabaseOpenHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mqn.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "quote";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_QUOTES = "quotesText";
public static final String COLUMN_AUTHOR= "author";
public static final String COLUMN_FAV = "fav";

private SQLiteDatabase database;

private final Context context;

// database path
private static String DATABASE_PATH;

/** constructor */
public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = ctx;
    DATABASE_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath()
            + "/databases/";

}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void create() throws IOException {
    boolean check = checkDataBase();

    SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;

    // Creates empty database default system path
    db_Read = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db_Read.close();
    try {
        if (!check) {
            copyDataBase();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Error copying database");
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 *
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

/** open the database */
public void open() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

/** close the database */
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null)
        database.close();
    super.close();
}

// insert a user into the database
public long insertUser(String quotesText, String author, String fav) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_QUOTES, quotesText );
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_AUTHOR, author);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_FAV, fav);
    return database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
}

// updates a user
public boolean updateUser(long rowId, String quotesText, String author,
                          String fav) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COLUMN_QUOTES, quotesText);
    args.put(COLUMN_AUTHOR, author);
    args.put(COLUMN_FAV, fav);
    return database.update(TABLE_NAME, args, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves a particular user
public Cursor getUser(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                    COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_QUOTES, COLUMN_AUTHOR, COLUMN_FAV },
            COLUMN_ID + " = " + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;
}

// delete a particular user
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) {
    return database.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves all users
public Cursor getAllUsers() {
    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
                    COLUMN_QUOTES, COLUMN_AUTHOR, COLUMN_FAV }, null, null,
            null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

**QuotesActivity.java**

```
public class QuotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView title;
Typeface myFont;
ListView quotesList;
ListView favLV;
DatabaseOpenHelper myDbHelper;
DatabaseAccess databaseAccess;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quotes);

    myDbHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this);

    try {
        // check if database exists in app path, if not copy it from assets
        myDbHelper.create();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
        // open the database
        myDbHelper.open();
        myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }

    populateListView();



    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_button);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleQuote);
    myFont =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Montserrat-Bold.otf");
    title.setTypeface(myFont);
    title.setTextSize(20);
    title.setTextColor(Color.rgb(240, 239, 223));

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

private void populateListView() {
    Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.getAllUsers();
    String[] from = new String[] {myDbHelper.COLUMN_QUOTES, myDbHelper.COLUMN_AUTHOR};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.quoteLV, R.id.authorLV};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.quotes_listview, cursor, from, to,0);
    quotesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.quotesList);
    quotesList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
}
```

**Content_quotes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="hendrasetiawan.mqn.QuotesActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_quotes">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/quotesList"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/favList"
            android:layout_weight="6" />


    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**quotes_listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/quoteLV"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/authorLV"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a prepopulated database, you have to make a copy of it (only the first run, meaning if the database is not already present in the proper path) into the standard database folder.

Once **there**, your database becomes writable, because you are no longer using the copy in the `assets` folder.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not very good, i dont quite understand what you mean.Can you check my edited post @Bob Malooga

Comment: It seems you're doing it right. What is now the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to update the favorite table when the user click the favorite button. please bear my noobness :|

Comment: Your question is different, and it seems you didn' get my answer correctly. You can't write the db in the assets folder. You must copy it where it can be edited and use that copy instead. Which is what you are doing. For the updates, that is **another question**.

Comment: So what you are saying is, i already copied my database? even though i put my database files in assets/databases??

Comment: by reading your code, which you seem not to understand very well (therefore I understand you copied it), I see that your db is copied from the assets folder to some (opinionable - not the standard path) location.

Comment: Yeah i just copied it :|| , i see , thank you so much